# Dnn search is not working for Html Module

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am using dnn7.3.2 and if am searching any html module content then am not getting any url of that html module in search box.

ex:-if am searching Bangalore then the search result is like this
Text/HTML
Bangalore 29th Main BTM Stage 1 Bangalore:...... Bangalore 29th Main BTM Stage 1 Bangalore: 560068, India. Phone: +91 80 41830000 AXA Group 25 avenue Matignon 75008 Paris France Phone: +33 1 4075 5700 Website: www.axa.com Pune 21/6, Bund Garden Road Pune – 411 001, India. Phone: +91 20 66079000 Panchshil Tech Park ...
if am clicking on Text/Html then its redirecting to search page.

Why this happen?is there anything i have to set in Admin?

Comment: What is the URL of the link in the search results?

Comment: url is:-/Search-Results/Search/bangalore

Comment: is that the URL of the SEARCH RESULTS PAGE you are browsing, or the LINK within the search results, or BOTH?

Comment: For both the case url is same.

Comment: I would start by trying to clear the search results and see if you can get the site to reindex. I would also upgrade to a newer release of DNN.